# Variable and function types in PHP 7.4 (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

Yesterday I was at an interview and after looking at my code I was told that I did not have enough typing, I still cannot understand how to use it in PHP, I will be grateful for your help

This is an example of my code(laravel)

https://github.com/MrKrist17/Reasons/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/ListOfReasonsController.php

(I'm asking for just an example of one of my functions, but with the addition of typing in the return and variables)

Comment: Welcome to SO .. sorry my friend but this is not right place

Comment: Why? I asdked the question and waiting for an answer, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you already have a typehint on the variable - ListOfReasons. This returns a laravel redirect response, so a return type hint would look like this:

```
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
...
  public function destroy(ListOfReasons $listOfReasons): RedirectResponse
    {
        Storage::disk('public')->delete($listOfReasons->photo);
        $listOfReasons->delete();
        return redirect()->route('adminIndex');
    }
```

Comment: Honestly asking for something like that to be in code is BS. Nobody defines return type on public controller functions that return response. Generating resource controller doesn't specify return type - I believe no-one should

Comment: I strongly disagree, NoOorZ24. The return type is known. Type hinting it helps make the code more readable, and also enforces expected behaviors. There is no valid reason NOT to type hint it. Doing so encourages ambiguity.

Comment: @JamesClarkDeveloper I think I misrepresented my view. I mean in other places - yes it's good to define return types. But saying that code of a junior is bad because it doesn't have return types defined for public functions seems like making a big deal of something this insignificant